# Find prime numbers using Array list

Tags: java

I want to find prime numbers given range using `ArrayList`. I have done following code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PrimeNumbers {
    
    
    public static void main(String args) {
        
        PrimeNumbers aaa=new PrimeNumbers();
        Iterator<Integer> itr = aaa.printAllPrime(1, 10).iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next()); 
        }
        
    }

    public  ArrayList<Integer> printAllPrime(int k, int j) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=k;i<=j;i++) {
            for(int l=1;l<=i;l++) {
                if(i%l == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(i+" "+count);
            if(count == 2) {
                arrlist.add(i);
            }
        }
        return arrlist;
    }

}
```

Expected:

`[2, 3, 5, 7]`

Current result:

`[2, 4, 3, 5, 10]`

I am fresh to java and please help me to find where I have done wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `count` inside the first `for` loop, before the second one. Since count is never reset to `0` after each iteration, you are getting the wrong number.

```
public  ArrayList<Integer> printAllPrime(int k, int j) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // int count=0; <- here is incorrect
        for(int i=k;i<=j;i++) {
            int count = 0; // put it here
            for(int l=1;l<=i;l++) {
                if(i%l == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(i+" "+count);
            if(count == 2) {
                arrlist.add(i);
            }
        }
        return arrlist;
    }
```

That way, `count` will be for each individual number.

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int l=1;l<=i;l++) {
                if(i%l == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
```

In this part of your code, you literally check if, for example 4%2 == 0,
ofc it is, so 4 is also put in the array.
Also, your code can be significantly improved with some simple math.

> So, if you test all the numbers up to the square root, you can rest
> assured that the number is prime. For example, the square root of 23
> is around 4.8, so you would test 23 to see if it can be divided by 2,
> 3 or 4. It cannot be, so 23 is prime.
> [Read more here](https://sciencing.com/calculate-coprime-6921150.html)

Comment: Liki How can change  my code get correct answer